# AndHUD Dialog not showing when called in Command

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I work on an android app who uses MvvmCross and AndHUD to display a progress dialog. I created an IDialogService interface and an implementation on Android:

```
    protected Activity CurrentActivity => Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity;


    /// <summary>
    ///     Shows a loading dialog on the whole display.
    /// </summary>
    public void ShowLoadingDialog()
    {
        AndHUD.Shared.Show(CurrentActivity, Strings.LoadingLabel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Closes the Loading Dialog.
    /// </summary>
    public void HideLoadingDialog()
    {
        AndHUD.Shared.Dismiss(CurrentActivity);
    }
```

The interface is injected via the constructor. When I call in the constructor:

```
        dialogService.ShowLoadingDialog();
```

it works perfectly.
But when I call it in the Command then nothing happens.

```
   public MvxCommand ImportContactsCommand => new MvxCommand(ImportContacts);


    private async void ImportContacts()
    {
        dialogService.ShowLoadingDialog();

        // logic

        dialogService.HideLoadingDialog();
        await dialogService.ShowMessage("Done!", "Import finished.");
    }
```

Interessting is, that the second dialog is called. Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I have to execute the logic async in a task:

```
 await Task.Run(() => Import());
```